# How to Implement Modular Animation Chunks in RealityKit/ARKit for Efficient Animation Blending?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am working on an AR application using RealityKit and ARKit where I need to implement character animations that are highly modular. The goal is to break down complex motions into smaller, reusable animation chunks that can be dynamically blended together at runtime.

For instance, I have several small animations for walking, running, jumping, etc., and I would like to blend these together seamlessly to create fluid and realistic character movement.

Questions:

What's the best approach to manage and play these modular animation chunks in RealityKit/ARKit?

Are there specific tools or frameworks that facilitate animation blending in RealityKit/ARKit?

How can I efficiently switch between these modular animations without causing jitter or animation snapping?

Any advice, best practices, or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

1. **Animation Chunk Creation:**

- **Create Animation Chunks:**
  Break down complex motions (walking, running, jumping) into smaller, manageable animation chunks.
- **Export and Import:**
  Export these animation chunks in a format compatible with RealityKit (e.g., USDZ, FBX) and import them into your project.

2. **Animation Blending:**

- **Define Blend Trees:**
- **Blend Shape Animation:**

#### 3. **Playing Animations Seamlessly:**

- **Transitions:**
  Implement smooth transitions between different animation chunks to avoid jitter or snapping. Use easing functions to interpolate between animation states.
- **Dynamic Blending:**
  Based on the character's actions or user input, dynamically adjust the blend weights for different animation chunks to achieve seamless transitions.

#### 4. **Implementation Tips and Best Practices:**

- **Use Animation Controllers:**
  RealityKit provides AnimationControllers that allow you to manage and blend animations. Utilize these controllers to handle animation states and blending.

5. **Sample Code:**

```swift
let animationMixer = Entity()

let walkingAnimation: AnimationResource = ...
let runningAnimation: AnimationResource = ...

// Create animation controllers for each animation chunk
let walkingController = walkingAnimation.repeat(duration: 1.0, transitionDuration: 0.25)
let runningController = runningAnimation.repeat(duration: 1.0, transitionDuration: 0.25)

// Add animation controllers to the AnimationMixer
animationMixer.add(walkingController)
animationMixer.add(runningController)

// Set blend weights based on character's movement speed
animationMixer[walkingController]!.blend = 0.5
animationMixer[runningController]!.blend = 0.5

arView.scene.anchors.append(animationMixer)
```

In this example, the `AnimationMixer` is used to blend two animation controllers (walking and running) based on the character's movement speed.

Note that I've referred to a website to top up the answer.